# Multiple source paths in batch-mode rule [nmake]

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, nmake

Im using the [batch-mode rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/batch-mode-rules?view=msvc-160) for my makefile. Currently i have the following targets:

```
DIR_SRC = src
DIR_INCLUDE = include
DIR_LIB = lib
DIR_BIN = bin\x64
DIR_BUILD = build\x64    

{$(DIR_SRC)}.cpp{$(DIR_BUILD)}.obj ::
            @echo Compiling...
cl /c /EHsc /Fo$(DIR_BUILD)\ /MD /I$(DIR_INCLUDE) $<
    
$(EXECUTABLE_NAME) : $(DIR_BUILD)\*.obj
   @echo Linking $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)...
   link /out:$(DIR_BIN)\$(EXECUTABLE_NAME) $(DIR_BUILD)\*.obj
```

The "bin/x64/*.obj" target uses all cpp files inside the "src" folder. Is it possible to add another source path to it?

I want something like this

```
{$(DIR_SRC) $(ANOTHER_DIR)}.cpp{$(DIR_BUILD)}.obj ::
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a *second* build directory to match your second source directory, you can get this to work.  For example, if we modify your makefile to be:

```
DIR_SRC = src
DIR_SRC2 = another
DIR_INCLUDE = include
DIR_BIN = bin\x64
DIR_BUILD = build\x64
DIR_BUILD2 = build_another\x64
EXECUTABLE_NAME = foo.exe    

{$(DIR_SRC)}.cpp{$(DIR_BUILD)}.obj ::
    @echo Compiling...
    cl -nologo /c /EHsc /Fo$(DIR_BUILD)\ /MD /I$(DIR_INCLUDE) $<
    
{$(DIR_SRC2)}.cpp{$(DIR_BUILD2)}.obj ::
    @echo Compiling...
    cl -nologo /c /EHsc /Fo$(DIR_BUILD2)\ /MD /I$(DIR_INCLUDE) $<
    
$(DIR_BIN)\$(EXECUTABLE_NAME) : $(DIR_BUILD)\*.obj $(DIR_BUILD2)\*.obj
    @echo Linking $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)...
    link -nologo /out:$@ $**
```

then we will get:

```
nmake -nologo

Compiling...
        cl -nologo /c /EHsc /Fobuild\x64\ /MD /Iinclude src\*.cpp
s1.cpp
s2.cpp
Generating Code...
Compiling...
        cl -nologo /c /EHsc /Fobuild_another\x64\ /MD /Iinclude another\*.cpp
a1.cpp
a2.cpp
Generating Code...
Linking foo.exe...
        link -nologo /out:bin\x64\foo.exe build\x64\*.obj build_another\x64\*.obj
```

where `src` contains `s1.cpp` and `s2.spp`, and where `another` contains `a1.cpp` and `a2.cpp`.